# Scala find element in nested List

Tags: scala

Consider the following example:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Family(surname: String, members: List[Person])

val families = List(
  Family("Jones",
    List(Person("Indiana", 50), Person("Molly", 20))),
  Family("Black",
    List(Person("Jack", 55), Person("Derek", 12))))
```

I want to write a function that finds a person with a certain name in a `List[Family]` object. This is my current solution:

```
def find(name: String, families: List[Family]): Option[Person] = {
  families.find(f => f.members.exists(m => m.name == name)).map(f => f.members.find(m => m.name == name).get)
}
```

Is there a more efficient and elegant (and functional) way to achieve this?

Comment: `families.flatMap(_.members).find(_.name == name)` does the job. But your data model appears badly chosen, because there is no way to get the surname of `Person`.

Comment: @ziggystar depends on how you want to process it, see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
families.flatMap(_.members).find(_.name == name)
```

Comment: Assuming you want to find only the first match, isn't it less efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Using a for comprehension like this,

```
for (f <- families; m <- f.members if m.name == name) yield m
```

Namely for each family member pick those whose name is as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `flatMap` and `find`:

```
families.flatMap(fam => fam.members).find(m => m.name == name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functionally I would prefer this way (added surname too, you probably need it, it makes it a bit more complicated):

```
families.flatMap { f => f.members
                         .find(_.name == "Molly")
                         .map { m => (f.surname, m.name) }}
        .headOption
//> res0: Option[(String, String)] = Some((Jones,Molly))
```

and if you want all people with the given name, just replace `.find` with `.filter` and remove `.headOption`

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to find just the family.

```
families.find(f => f.members.exists(_.name == name))
```