# Scala select an element from a list based on that element's sublist properties

Tags: scala, list

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065098/scala-find-element-in-nested-list), but a little different.

I have a `List[Family]`, and each `Family` keeps a `List[People]` and I want to select the first Family if that Family has a Person by the name I'm looking for

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Family(surname: String, members: List[Person])

def findFamilyByPerson(families:List[Family], personName:String): Family = ??? 

val per1 = Person("Tina", 4)
val per2 = Person("Mike", 15)
val per3 = Person("Mary", 77)
val per4 = Person("John",34)
val fam1 = Family("Hetfield", List(per1, per2))
val fam2 = Family("McCoy", List(per3, per4))

println(findFamilyByPerson(List(fam1, fam2), "Mary").surname) // should print "McCoy"
```

I tried defining `findFamilyByPerson` as:

```
def findFamilyByPerson(families:List[Family], personName:String): Family = {
     families.flatMap(_.members).find(_.name == personName) 
 }
```

but this returns an `Option[Person]`, when what I want is that Person's `Family`

I'm guessing it has something to do with flatMap and Find, but just not quite sure how to work that out.

Comment: `families.find { _.exists(_.name == personName) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def findFamilyByPerson(families:List[Family], personName:String): Option[Family] = {
     families.find(_.members.exists(_.name == personName)) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ScalaFiddle for demonstration: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/AM1IH3u/0